# Adding .xib , .h & . m to an existing storyboard.

Tags: ios, xcode

I am very new at iOS programing and Xcode. I have learned a lot. And most of it from this forem but I just can't find the answer to what I think is such a basic question.

I have started a new project using Xcode 4.5 that has a storyboard. The storyboard is just the basic two view storyboard. My app needs a "start up" view. While I've been able, through "add file" to add the view (.xib) file. I don't see a way to include this view ( and it's .h & .m) to the storyboard. I would think it would be basically drag & drop but I see no such option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

File..> New>File>Objective C File > Class name (yourname) Subclass of: UIViewController and click on the checkbox for: "With XIB for User Interface"

Good Luck

Comment: If this helped you enough. Please mark it as accepted. If it didnt help you, please tell me what you want or what went wrong

Comment: Thanks that did create the three new files but they don't show as part of the storyboard. How do I insure this is where the app starts?

Comment: I think this'll help you - : http://kurrytran.blogspot.nl/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html

Comment: I think the only thing that you were missing here was to click on the view in the storyboard and change the custom class to the name of the files you added.